# Prometheus alert not peding/firing at second time

Tags: prometheus

I have this simple Prometheus alert configured

```
ALERT MyServiceDown
  IF my_custom_metric == 0
  FOR 15s
```

Scenario is as follows:

1. In the correct runtime my_custom_metric is 1, and MyServiceDown alert is green at Alert tab.
2. Then I set my_custom_metric 0 and Propetheus retrieves it as 0, which I can see at Graph -> Console tab.
3. MyServiceDown immediately becomes Pending (yellow) and after 15 seconds becomes Firing (red).
4. Then I "fix bug", my_custom_metric is 1 again, and MyServiceDown alert is green.

Here comes strange part. I break app second time so that my_custom_metric is 0 again. It is shown at Graph -> Console. But MyServiceDown alert never pending or firing. When I restart Prometheus everything works good, but only once.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There was bug in version 0.17rc1

https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/1372

It fixed in 0.17rc2

Problem solved.